# JPackage (incubator) and SQLite database problem

Tags: java, javafx, jar, jpackage

I could use some help again, out of ideas. :(
I am making JavaFX application that will use SQLite database. OpenJDK 14 with OpenJFX14 is used. In my Eclipse all is working perfectly. I tried for test to make installer with JPackage and that worked too. When I start installed application it starts ok, but for some reason refuse to connect with database.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I have a button where when Stage is loaded I check connection. It is in file PocetnaController:

```
    //testiranje konekcije nakon instalacije
@FXML
public void btnObracunClick(ActionEvent event) {
    lblStatus.setText(model.povezanaBaza());
}
```

And this is code from PocetnaModel that is called:

```
    public String povezanaBaza() {
    this.konekcija = Konekcija.poveziBazu();
    return (this.konekcija != null) ? "Веза са базом успостављена" : "Повезивање са базом није успело.";
}
```

When true it returns "Database connection established" in my language and when false "Connection with database failed".

I repeat, in Eclipse all works well. But, when start installed app I am getting "Connection with database failed". So connection returning null for some reason.

My db file is coppied by JPackage in /app folder. I tried to copy manualy Porez.db to root folder where *.exe is. Strange thing, status label doesn't change in that case. And it should, it must return true or false, don't understand that.

This is stage look when started:

[image]

Even if I rename database file in /app folder, so it can't be found my connection still returning false and update status accordingly which is ok.

Here is entire Konekcija file who has a role to take care of connection:

```
    public static Connection poveziBazu() {
    File baza = new File("Porez.db");
    try {
        if (baza.exists()) {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Porez.db");
            return con;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My first suspect is something is wrong with my created JAR, but can't be sure. Makes no sense to me to work in Eclipse and no after install.

Comment: You cannot have your database file inside your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several places you need to check and possibly fix if you ran jpackage with:

```
 jpackage --name SQLiteTest --input C:\Users\Dalibor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SQLiteTest\dist --main-jar SQLiteTest.jar --runtime-image hello\myjre
```

Turn on Windows console so that you can see the error messages it is providing - use `jpackage  --win-console`.

After installing your jpackaged release, check the release directory structure.

1. Make sure it contains the sqllite-jdbc.jar file.
   If NOT found fix your `--input` directories to add the jar.
2. Check the `app\xxx.cfg` file for your generated application.
   It must contain all your jar dependencies including sqlite-jdbc.jar such as:

   ```
   app.classpath=$ROOTDIR\app\jars\xxxx.jar;$ROOTDIR\app\jars\sqlite-jdbc.jar
   ```
3. Check that the jlink command you used to build the runtime image `hello\myjre` includes `--add-modules java.sql` to combine with the required SQL dependencies.
4. The app structure created by the installer that jpackage builds is different to the structure you have in Eclipse - files are under `app` directory, and most importantly the release is only editable with Administrator privileges. Use System property `java.launcher.path` to adjust the location of the SqlLite database to an editable location
   and don't mask exceptions:

   ```
    public static Connection poveziBazu() {
        File baza = new File("Porez.db");
        String jhome = System.getProperty("java.launcher.path");
        if (jhome != null) {
            baza = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Porez.db");
        }
        System.out.println("Connecting to "+baza.getAbsolutePath()+" exists()="+baza.exists());
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+baza.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed connecting to: "+baza);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open or create db: "+baza, e);
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but I didn't managed to make it run so I tried simplified version. No MVC, just stage with Button and Label that trying to set connection on button click. It seems there is the problem.

https://ibb.co/dJbv1ZZ

Stage loads, and after I click on Button no change.

Comment: Same happens even if I set test.db to absolute path like C://test.db. I don't understand. :(

Comment: What exception or message is printed? Also check you included SqlLite jars with the jpackage or jlink runtime.

Comment: No message is returned. Label doesn't change at all, nothing. I don't know how to include sqlite jar in jlink, but I put it in same location as project jar and it was copied in app folder in Program Files. This is my jpackage string: jpackage --name SQLiteTest --input C:\Users\Dalibor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SQLiteTest\dist --main-jar SQLiteTest.jar --runtime-image hello\myjre

Comment: Your issue is that you've not packaged sqllite into your generated image, so the driver classes won't be loaded when launching the generated EXE. I'll amend my answer.